# Site template for SharePoint 2010 Intranet Portal

Tags: moss, sharepoint-2010

What site template would you recommend to create an intranet portal site? It is going to be used by 200 employees. It probably will have the following content

1. department calendar
2. company news
3. employee search
4. weather
5. useful links
6. new employee list
7. presentation video

User should be able to customize the portal based their interests. Kind like the iGoogle where you could add widgets and move them around.

Maybe I also could use Fab 40 templates (for MOSS 2010), not sure yet. http://techsolutions.net/Blog/tabid/65/EntryId/17/Fab-40-Templates-for-MOSS-2010.aspx

Comment: Correction: the intranet portal is for the department which has groups and teams. The corporate has gazillion employees and departments, but it's not my concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this isn't available directly out of the box.
But if it's for an intranet website, I'd choose a Team Site or an Empty site.

With an empty site, you can add everything you want/need yourself, the team site already has a calendar, document list, etc.

On a side-note. Most of the time when I create an intranet portal it's in the following setup:

http://intranet 
-> contains all company info (company agenda, docs, news, etc.)
http://intranet/department1 
-> contains all info of the department

http://intranet/department1/group1 -> info about group1

http://intranet/department1/group1/team1 -> info about team1.

Off-course, if you haven't got any groups or teams, you don't need those and you can stick with the 2 levels (root and department-sites).
Also, you can create site templates of the department sites, so all of them are the same.

Some webparts probably need to be created by youself, but everything is quite doable with an empty or team site.

PS:
Sharepoint 2010 only has SPS or SPF. 
Sharepoint 2007 has MOSS or WSS3.0

Comment: In that case, I would have to choose either blank or team site as the root of department intranet and have each group in its own site collection and teams in subsite. Would you recommend create portal starting in central administration or directly in visual studio instead?

Comment: I'd create a new web application (intranet) in Central Administration. In there I'd create a new site collection on the root (with the empty or team template). In the site collection I'd create subsites (not more site collections), as you'll be able to use stuff from the root site, otherwise you won't be able to query lists (and users) from the root site.